# Rails: foreign keys - how does the DB table looks like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have found this example here on stack overflow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :winners, class_name: "Competition", foreign_key: "competition_id"
end

class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :winner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "winner_id"
end
```

1. What exactly is the "has_many: **winners**" or "belongs_to: **winner**" in this case?
2. Is there a "competition_id" column in the users table and a "winner_id" column in the competitions table?

Greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables would look something like:

```
users:
  id: integer,
  # other fields - name, email etc.

competitions:
  id: integer,
  winner_id: integer,
  # other fields - name, place etc.
```

When someone uses the winners has_many association, for example like:

```
User.find(3).winners
```

it'll do a query that ends up as something like:

```
SELECT * FROM competitions WHERE winner_id = 3 # the 3 here comes from the user's id
```

When someone uses the winner belongs_to association, for example like:

```
Competition.find(4).winner
```

it'll do a query that ends up as something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 # the 1 here has come from the winner_id on the competition record
```

The winners association is possibly poorly named; won_competitions would likely be a better name.

More reading: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html